# Serialize to XML and ignore objects with no value set

Tags: vb.net, xml-serialization

I am retrieving and deserializing XML, updating a single object value, then (re) serializing to XML.

The retrieved XML only includes fields that have a value (i.e. the application that creates this XML evidently ignores nulls and zeros).

However, my code (below) serializes ALL objects in the class, even if I have not set a value.

In essence, I only want to return the values that I have retrieved and ignore the rest.

Suffice it to say, the code does exactly what I am asking it to do, just not what I want it to do (below is edited for brevity but includes relevant elements):

```
Private Sub Update_Name()

        'write 'name' to xml file

        Dim table As New table() ' 'table' is the name of my CLASS
        Dim serializer As New XmlSerializer(table.GetType())
        Dim ns As New XmlSerializerNamespaces()
        ns.Add("", "")
        Using reader = XmlReader.Create("C:/mwName_in.xml")
            table = CType(serializer.Deserialize(reader), table)
        End Using

        'update fields in xml table and save to file


        Dim name = table.name
        For Each nm In name
            nm.custom4 = "Subscriber" ' this is the only value that I am setting/updating

            Dim writer As XmlWriter

            Using writer = XmlWriter.Create("C:/mwName_out.xml")

                serializer.Serialize(writer, table, ns)
            End Using

            'THIS IS WHERE I POST THE RESULTING XML

        Next

End Sub
```

My 'incoming' XML looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<table found="6" start="0" count="6" name="Name">
  <name>
    <code>AWEBSTER</code>
    <name>Alex Webster</name>
    <address1>West End Road</address1>
    <address2>Herne Bay</address2>
    <address3>Auckland</address3>
    <delivery1>West End Road</delivery1>
    <delivery2>Herne Bay</delivery2>
    <delivery3>Auckland</delivery3>
    <delivery4>Auckland</delivery4>
    <phone>021555 8888</phone>
    <category1>SHOP</category1>
    <category2>NZ</category2>
    <customertype>2</customertype>
    <debtorterms>-20</debtorterms>
    <creditorterms>-20</creditorterms>
    <recaccount>5500</recaccount>
    <payaccount>6500</payaccount>
    <suppliertype>2</suppliertype>
    <email>test@test.com</email>
    <productpricing>B</productpricing>
  </name>
</table>
```

My outgoing XML looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<table>
 <name>
  <hold>false</hold>
  <dateoflastsale>0001-01-01T00:00:00</dateoflastsale>
  <supplierpropmtpaymentterms>0</supplierpropmtpaymentterms>
  <custpromptpaymentterms>0</custpromptpaymentterms>
  <customertype>2</customertype>
  <suppliertype>2</suppliertype>
  <colour>0</colour>
  <d30plus>0</d30plus>
  <d60plus>0</d60plus>
  <d90plus>0</d90plus>
  <discount>0</discount>
  <ccurrent>0</ccurrent>
  <dcurrent>0</dcurrent>
  <creditorterms>-20</creditorterms>
  <debtorterms>-20</debtorterms>
  <paymentmethod>0</paymentmethod>
  <lastpaymentmethod>0</lastpaymentmethod>
  <splitpercent>0</splitpercent>
  <supppromptpaymentdiscount>0</supppromptpaymentdiscount>
  <receiptmethod>0</receiptmethod>
  <custpropmtpaymentdiscount>0</custpropmtpaymentdiscount>
  <dbalance>0</dbalance>
  <creditlimit>0</creditlimit>
  <kind>0</kind>
  <usernum>0</usernum>
  <lastmodifiedtime>0001-01-01T00:00:00</lastmodifiedtime>
  <abuid>0001-01-01T00:00:00</abuid>
  <delivery1>West End Road</delivery1>
  <delivery4>Auckland</delivery4>
  <delivery2>Herne Bay</delivery2>
  <delivery3>Auckland</delivery3>
  <email>test@test.com</email>
  <custom4>Subscriber</custom4>
  <address1>West End Road</address1>
  <address2>Herne Bay</address2>
  <address3>Auckland</address3>
  <name>Alex Webster</name>
  <phone>0215558888</phone>
  <productpricing>B</productpricing>
  <payaccount>6500</payaccount>
  <recaccount>5500</recaccount>
  <code>AWEBSTER</code>
  <category1>SHOP</category1>
  <category2>NZ</category2>
 </name>
</table>
```

Evidently, the serialization has picked up all of the objects in the classes 'table' and 'name', but I only want the ones with values set (i.e. those that were in the incoming XML and the one value that I updated - 'custom4', in this case).

The problem being that I can't use XmlIgnore (at least I don't think I can) because I don't know in advance which fields will be set and which will be null/zero - and I only need to update the one field.

I have not included the whole class - it does successfully serialize to the outgoing XML (above).

Many thanks in advance.  This is kinda making me crazy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this purpose, it seems overkill to hydrate a whole object, then re-serialize it back to XML.  Instead, you can use the `System.Xml.Linq` namespace as follows (code in C#, but easily transferred to VB.NET)

```
var doc = XDocument.Load("c:/oldfile.xml");
var custom4 = doc.Root.Element("name").Element("custom4");
custom4.Value = "whatever";
doc.Save("c:/newfile.xml");
```

Comment: Thanks CSJ.  I take your point and LINQ may be the way to go.  This is part of a larger project, the classes are already witten and I had thought I was following best practice until I hit this impasse.